# How to operate a function over multiple columns (Pandas/Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics

Let's consider IBM HR Attrition Dataset from Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/pavansubhasht/ibm-hr-analytics-attrition-dataset). How do I rapdly gets the variable with the highest Shapiro p-value?

In other words, I can apply a function `shapiro()` in a column as `shapiro(df['column'])`. And I would like to calculate for all the numeric columns these function.

I tried this:

```
from scypy.stats import shapiro
df = pd.read_csv('path')

#here i was expecting the output to be a sequential prints with the name of the columns and their respective p-value from shapiro()
for col in hr:
   print(col," : ", shapiro(hr[col])[0])
```

Anyone that could help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps! I'm sure there are a lot better ways, but it was fun trying :)

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
```

```
df = pd.read_csv('path.csv')
```

```
# make a new dataframe newdf with only the columns containing numeric data

numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']

newdf = df.select_dtypes (include=numerics)
```

```
#check to see that the columns are only numeric
print(newdf.head())
```

```
# new dataframe with rows "W" and "P"
shapiro_wilks = (newdf).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(shapiro(x), index=['W','P'])).reset_index()
shapiro_wilks = shapiro_wilks.set_index('index') #ugh


print(shapiro_wilks)
```